# How to choose whether to pickle class instances or just save a file with a list of arguments in python

Tags: python, pickle

I am doing a python module to perform engineering calculations on pressure vessels (not homework).  Previously I have done this in excel but I am trying to move it into Python because a) I think it will work better b) I want to try it out.  I suspect that it is well suited to be moved out of excel because many calculations are the same and done repeatedly on different items or different combinations of vessel, geometry, stress loads, etc.  The good thing about excel I am realising now is that you save your sheet(s) and you when you reopen the file you haven't lost any data!

So I have set up my module to have a class for the pressure vessel, one (or more) for the branch attached to it, one (or more) for the load cycle that applies to the vessel, one for the material properties that apply to that vessel during that load cycle, and finally one for the resultant stresses that apply to the combination of branch, vessel, load cycle, material properties.  Generally my instances aren't modified after creation (although perhaps I will want them to be later?) and they need between 3 and 8 arguments to be defined.

If I go away and come back I have to type in a lot of information so I want to be able to save (and load) my work.  As I see it I could either:

1. Figure out a way to save a list of instance creation arguments to a file. I'm sure its not that hard.
2. Learn how to pickle the classes (if it is at all possible in this instance).

I'm not a programmer so I might be missing something key about pickling.  You learned guys(and gals) are so I'm just asking for guidance.  Is pickling an unnecessary layer of complexity? Or is it a vastly beneficial way to proceed without limiting my future options? It has occurred to me that figuring out a way to write and read a file with args as lists might be tantamount to preparing classes to be pickled but I don't really know how hard it will be.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Secondly I'd like to say that this forum is great and although I've never asked, I've benefited a lot from others' questions and all of your answers.

Comment: I would venture to guess that pickling will just work ... its easy and it gets the job done ...

Comment: Pickling is simple, if your class does not have any unusual behaviours then you may not need to do anything in order to correctly pickle them. Otherwise, defining `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods appropriately should do the job. See section 11.1.5 in the Python pickle module online docs.